# Condition dosen't work on filtered data

Tags: excel, conditional-statements, vba

1. Filter data with number > 0
2. Select the cells visible with data and make them "0"
3. Remove filter

My code works fine when there are NO ROWS and more than ONE ROW after filter. But fails when there is only one row left after filter. Can somebody help ?

```
Rows("1:1").Select
Range("C1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter
ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$98").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
Range("C1").Select
ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
Loop
If ActiveCell = vbNullString Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$98").AutoFilter Field:=3
Else
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "0"
    Selection.Copy
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$J$98").AutoFilter Field:=3
End If
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FilterAndCopy()
    With Range("A1:J98")
        .AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=">0"
        .Copy Range("THE_RANGE_YOU_NEED_TO_COPY_TO")
        .AutoFilter
    End With
End Sub
```

**Explanation**

After filtering a range, the `Copy` method copies only visible cells. The `Destination` argument of `Copy` is the location where you want to paste data (it could be any worksheet).

Comment: It would ve wise to explicitly reference the worksheet you are using, instead of hoping you have the right worksheet active.

Comment: @MZaragoza All is simple - after filtering a range, the `Copy` method copies only visible cells. The `Destination` argument of `Copy` is the location where you want to paste data.

Comment: @MZaragoza Updated answer

Comment: Hi, Dosent work because when only one row is visible after the filter, this formula takes the last TO cell (non-blank) in the worksheet. So the formula is pasted for all :(

Answer (score 0):

It is simpler if you use the SpecialCells(xlVisible) and the Intersect commands.

```
Sub tt()
Set sh = ActiveSheet
If sh.FilterMode Then sh.AutoFilterMode = False
Set r = sh.Range("$A1:$J$98")
Field = 3
r.AutoFilter Field:=Field, Criteria1:=">0", Operator:=xlAnd
Set FilterData = Intersect(r, r.Offset(1))
Set VisibleData = Nothing
On Error Resume Next
Set VisibleData = FilterData.SpecialCells(xlVisible)
On Error GoTo 0
If VisibleData Is Nothing Then
Else
 VisibleData.Columns(Field).Cells.Formula = "0"
End If
sh.AutoFilterMode = False
End Sub
```